# plotly adding a source or caption to a chart

Tags: r, plotly

Is there a way to add a data source / caption to a chart in Plotly, similar with what can be done in `ggplot` with the caption argument:

```
labs(caption = "source: data i found somewhere")
```

i.e., so we can display the data source at the bottom right of the graph, in a smaller font.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`annotation` offers a simple way to add a caption to a chart in `plotly`:

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly(x=~hp, y=~mpg, data=mtcars, type="scatter", mode="marker") %>% 
 layout(annotations = 
 list(x = 1, y = -0.1, text = "Source: data I found somewhere.", 
      showarrow = F, xref='paper', yref='paper', 
      xanchor='right', yanchor='auto', xshift=0, yshift=0,
      font=list(size=15, color="red"))
 )
```

[image] .

More details are given [here](https://community.plot.ly/t/left-align-source-annotation-or-axis-title-for-source-below-x-axis/4020/2) and [here](https://plot.ly/create/?fid=plotly2_demo:128).

Comment: Thanks Marco, but ggplot already has labs for that.  My question is specifically to do that but in plotly.

Comment: @chrisjacques I edited my answer. Now you can find a way to add a caption to your plotly chart. If this solution can help you, please consider to upvote it.

Comment: I found adding `margin = list(b=90)` into `layout(...)` function and setting `y = -0.2` helped to add longer caption and to ensure there was space (and it would show) in margin

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a `ggplot` graph, you can convert it to `plotly` using [ggplotly](https://plotly.com/ggplot2/getting-started/) and still add a caption using the same `layout` function like this:

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() 

ggplotly(p) %>%
  layout(margin = list(l = 50, r = 50, b = 100, t = 50),
         annotations = list(x = 1, y = -0.3, text = "Source: data I found somewhere.",
                            xref='paper', yref='paper', showarrow = F, 
                            xanchor='right', yanchor='auto', xshift=0, yshift=0,
                            font = list(size = 10)))
```

Output:

[image]

So this makes it possible to use `ggplot` as a `plotly` graph.

Comment: Can `Source` be made bold by adding `**Source**`?

Comment: Hi @Ed_Gravy, If you want to make `Source` bold, you could use HTML syntax like this: `<b>Source</b>` which will make it bold.

Comment: Thank you, should I post this as a question so others might find it useful too? I will using your code as reference though?

Comment: @Ed_Gravy, No problem! Glad it helped. That could be useful indeed. Maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50067301/make-plotly-annotation-font-bold) also helps.

Answer (score 0):

This was what I was looking for, but it don't produce the same result as expected when I run it - the text didn't show. I edited and tested and got the text to show. But I don't understand all the arguments within the list, could you explain?

Here are some of them I think got figured out.

- `xref` and `yref`: "paper" - suggest some ref. to the plot-area (but from where, i.e. what point I don't know)
- `x` and `y` - moving the text in decimal %(?) from some point, increasing x - right, increasing y - up
- `showarrow` - is self-explanitory

Thanks!