# Make plotly annotation font bold

Tags: r, fonts, plotly

I'd like to add `annotation` to a `scatter` plot generated by `R`'s `plotly` package, and have the text appear in bold.

I'm trying:

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(10),y=rnorm(10))
plotly::plot_ly(x =~ df$x, y =~ df$y,marker = list(size=12), type = 'scatter',mode = "markers") %>%
  plotly::add_annotations(text=1:10,showarrow=T,arrowhead=1,x=df$x,y=df$y,font=list(size=10))
```

Which gives:
[image]

Trying to add `face="bold"` to the `font` specification `list`:

```
plotly::plot_ly(x =~ df$x, y =~ df$y,marker = list(size=12), type = 'scatter',mode = "markers") %>%
  plotly::add_annotations(text=1:10,showarrow=T,arrowhead=1,x=df$x,y=df$y,font=list(size=10,face="bold"))
```

Doesn't really change anything:
[image]

So the question is how to get that text annotation to appear in bold.

P.S.
In my real data I'd like to annotate clusters of points hence the annotations come as a separate layer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simply enter your text as HTML, like so:

```
plotly::plot_ly(x =~ df$x, y =~ df$y,marker = list(size=12), type = 'scatter',mode = "markers") %>%
  plotly::add_annotations(text=sprintf("<b>%s</b>", 1:10),showarrow=T,arrowhead=1,x=df$x,y=df$y,font=list(size=10))
```

Comment: This works in python too. Put your text in between `<b>` and `</b>`.