# How can I add a caption to an R plotly scatterplot?

Tags: r, r-plotly

I'm trying to add a caption to a basic plot_ly to include more information about the scatter plot I have.

I've had a look at this thread:
[plotly adding a source or caption to a chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45103559/plotly-adding-a-source-or-caption-to-a-chart) but the caption here is inline with the x-axis title.

I can't seem to get the caption underneath the plot and x-axis title.

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that's easy for folks to help with. That includes code you've tried already, any necessary data, and a clear sense of what you're trying to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with the post you link to, you need to set the `margin` in the `plot_ly` `layout` and then change the `x`, and `y` in the `annotations`

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly(x=~hp, y=~mpg, data=mtcars, type="scatter", mode="marker") %>% 
  layout(margin = list(b=160), ##bottom margin in pixels
         annotations = 
           list(x = 0.5, y = -0.75, #position of text adjust as needed 
                text = "Source: data I found somewhere.", 
                showarrow = F, xref='paper', yref='paper', 
                xanchor='right', yanchor='auto', xshift=0, yshift=0,
                font=list(size=15, color="red"))
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This was perfect